# passing argument 4 of 'qsort' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some trouble with a function we are supposed to be writing. Supposedly, this is how it should work, but it's giving me the incompatible pointer type error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

The issue is in the qsort referencing the compare_last function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PERSONS 100

//person structure definition goes here
typedef struct{
    char last[32];
    char first[32];
    int year;
}Person;

//function declarations go here
int compare_last(Person * ptr1, Person * ptr2);

void main(void){//main function goes here
    char *infilename[20];
    char *outfilename[20];
    FILE * fptrin;
    FILE * fptrout;
    int i, j;
    Person musicians[MAX_PERSONS];
    printf("Enter input file name: ");
    scanf("%s", infilename);
    printf("Enter output file name: ");
    scanf("%s", outfilename);
    strcat(*outfilename, ".htm");
    fptrin = fopen(*infilename, "r");
    fptrout = fopen(*outfilename, "w");

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_PERSONS; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptrin, "%s %s %i", musicians[i].last, musicians[i].first, &musicians[i].year);
    }

    qsort(musicians, i, sizeof(musicians[0]), compare_last);

    fprintf(fptrout, "<html>\n<body>\n<title>LAB14</title>\n");

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        fprintf(fptrout, "%s %s %i <br>", musicians[j].last, musicians[j].first, musicians[j].year);
    }

    fprintf(fptrout, "</body>\n</html>\n");
    fclose(fptrin);
    fclose(fptrout);

}//end main

//function definitions go here

int compare_last(Person * ptr1, Person * ptr2)
{
    int result = strcmp(ptr1 -> last, ptr2 -> last);
    if(result != 0)
        return result;
    else
        return strcmp(ptr1 -> first, ptr2 -> first); 
}
```

Comment: You write `we are supposed to be writing` - does this mean this is homework?

Answer (score 4):

```
int compare_last(Person * ptr1, Person * ptr2);
```

should be

```
int compare_last(void * ptr1, void * ptr2);
```

Then you need to cast within `compare_last`

Comment: Okay, so how do I cast the pointers? Everything I'm trying isn't working and I can't find any solutions.

Comment: `Person * personPtr1 = (Person *) ptr1;`

Comment: It's still giving me the incompatible pointer type error....am I using qsort wrong? I changed the code to int compare_last(void * ptr1, void * ptr2)
{
Person * personPtr1 = (Person *) ptr1;
Person * personPtr2 = (Person *) ptr2;
int result = strcmp(personPtr1 -> last, personPtr2 -> last);
if(result != 0)
return result;
else
return strcmp(personPtr1 -> first, personPtr2 -> first); 
}

Comment: @Sam: make sure you change the prototype for `compare_last()` too.

Comment: I did, the prototype and the function are the same.

Comment: I figured it out, I make the names of the files at the top pointers for some reason, so my error ended up being that the program wasn't actually writing to the files. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually the parameters to the callback function should both be `const void *`.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype for `qsort()` is:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int(*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Thus, your sorting function needs to either match `int(*compar)(const void *, const void *)`, or you need to cast when calling qsort().

If you want to sort `Person*`, the easiest way is to declare your sorting function as required, then cast inside the function:

```
static int compare_last(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const Person *p1 = ptr1, *p2 = ptr2;
    int result = strcmp(p1 -> last, p2 -> last);
    ...
}
```

there's no need at all to cast then, since `const void *` converts just fine to `const Person *`.

Comment: Casting a non-matching function pointer here will invoke undefined behavior since `qsort` will call it with the wrong argument types (`const void *` instead of `Person *`).

Comment: @R.: Okay, good to know. I expect  most compilers to generate something sensible there, since const void * and Person * are both pretty likely to be represented in the same way, but undefinedness is of course worth avoiding.

Comment: Yeah, in practice (and on POSIX) all pointers have the same representation, but it's best to avoid relying on that if you don't really need to and there's an alternative way to write the code that's clear and 100% conformant.