# standard way to solve "passing argument of function from incompatible pointer type" with function pointers parameter

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, c99

I have a `list` module implementing a foward list, like the following (minimal working example):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct list_cell {
    void* payload;
    struct list_cell* next;
};

struct list {
    struct list_cell* head;
    int length;
};

typedef bool(*matcher_t)(const void* data);

void* findElementInList(struct list* l, matcher_t matcher) {
    struct list_cell* tmp = l->head;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (matcher(tmp->payload)) {
        return tmp->payload;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    return NULL;
} 

struct person {
    char* name;
    char* surname;
};


static char* constName = "Thomas";
bool matchByName(const struct person* p) {
    printf("comparing %s with %s\n", p->name, constName);
    return strcmp(p->name, constName) == 0;
}

int main() {
    //initializations (made by hand to have a MWE)
    struct person globalThomas = {"Thomas", "Lot"};

    struct list* l = (struct list*) malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    l->head = (struct list_cell*) malloc(sizeof(struct list_cell));
    l->head->payload = &globalThomas;
    l->head->next = NULL;
    l->length = 1;

    void* el = findElementInList(l, matchByName);
    if (el != NULL) {
    printf("found Thomas!\n");
    } else {
    printf("Thomas not found!\n");
    }
    //deallocation
    free(l->head);
    free(l);
}
```

Compiling this with gcc will generate the following warning:

```
list.c:57:34: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘findElementInList’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  void* el = findElementInList(l, matchByName);
                                  ^
list.c:18:7: note: expected ‘matcher_t {aka _Bool (*)(const void *)}’ but argument is of type ‘_Bool (*)(const struct person *)’
 void* findElementInList(struct list* l, matcher_t matcher) {
```

This happens because `matcher_t` defined its parameter with `void*` but we inject `struct person*`. I want to solve this warning but I'm uncertain about the best way to solve it. Clearly (as proposed in [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5865594/1887602)) I can solve it by changing `matchByName` signature to `matchByName(const void* p)` and by casting `void*` pointer into `struct person*`. But I feel like this make the function the function purpose: by looking at the header only, I can't determine what is the input of the function. Leaving `struct person*` makes it instead clear.

So my question is: **What the best method to solve this warning? What do you usually do to solve it? Is there another way to solve it aside changing `matchByName` signature?**.

Thanks for any kind reply

PS: the objective here is to add `-Werror` flag in compilation in order to make the code more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, this is the best you can do:

```
bool matchByName(const void *px)
{
    const struct person *p = px;

    printf("comparing %s with %s\n", p->name, constName);
    return strcmp(p->name, constName) == 0;
}
```

You have to make the function signature match its caller's expectation, and its caller is a pseudo-generic so it has to pass `const void *` rather than a concrete type.  There is no way around this.  But by assigning the untyped parameter to a variable with the correct concrete type as the first statement in the function, you make things clear for a human reading the code, and that's the best you can do.

Incidentally, you really ought to get rid of that `constName` global variable, by having `findElementInList` accept an additional `const void *` parameter that it passes down to the matcher unmolested:

```
bool matchByName(const void *px, const void *cx)
{
    const struct person *p = px;
    const char *nameToMatch = cx;

    printf("comparing %s with %s\n", p->name, constName);
    return strcmp(p->name, constName) == 0;
}

void *findElementInList(struct list *l, matcher_t matcher,
                        const void *matcher_args)
{
     struct list_cell *tmp = l->head;
     while (tmp) {
         if (matcher(tmp->payload, matcher_args)) {
             return tmp->payload;
         }
         tmp = tmp->next;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Please also note the stylistic corrections I have made to your code:

- For historical reasons, in C preferred style is to put the opening curly brace of a function definition on its own line, even if all other opening curly braces are "cuddled" with their statement head.  In some code you will also see the return type on its own line, which I think makes sense when there are often a lot of qualifiers on the return type, but don't do that unless you're going to do it *consistently* throughout the entire codebase.
- The `*` in a pointer declaration binds to the thing on its *right*, not the thing on its left, so it should always be written with a space to its left and no space to its right.  Everyone who says otherwise is wrong.
- Explicit comparisons of pointers with NULL/0 are bad style; just write `if (ptr)` (or, in this case, `while (ptr)`).  I personally think NULL itself is bad style and you should write 0 instead, but reasonable people can disagree about that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I thought it was the only way to solve the warning, but I needed to confirm my hypothesis. As for the stylistic corrections, I still need to grasp why `void *foo()` is preferred over `void* foo()`: I mean, the only drawback is the declaration of several variables on the same line, which IMHO is bad code style. It also create confusion with the dereference operation. But I think I will need to post a question about it :)

Comment: @Koldar There's probably several other questions about that already and a new one will probably get closed as "opinion-based".  You're right that left-cuddled `*` is only _hazardous_ (in the sense that it might make the program buggy) if you have several variables in the same declaration (not necessarily on the same line) but it causes _confusion to human readers_ regardless, and most of the time readability is the single most important property code can have.

Comment: I need to think about that... anyway thanks for the introspection. Always loved to know others form mentis on such debated questions. :)

Comment: I have to down vote this because of the 100% subjective coding style arguments. I could argue against all of them but this is not the place for it. There is no reason for bringing in subjective, personal coding style into an otherwise fine answer - if you change the style of the posted code that's fine, but there's no need to derail with arguments about why this style is supposedly superior.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are only compatible if their types are identical. To wildly convert from one type to the other is strictly speaking undefined behavior (although some cases may work as a non-standard extension on many systems).

So you will either need to use the very same type in all cases, or write a wrapper function such as this:

```
inline bool matchByName (const void* p)
{
  return matchByNamePerson (p);
}
```

That being said, generic programming with void pointers is old-fashioned C and quite dangerous. Nowadays you should preferably write fully type-safe code instead:

```
_Generic matchByName ((p), \
                      const struct person*: matchByNamePerson, \
                      const struct thing*:  matchByNameThing)(p)
```

Comment: Hasn't that syntax been introduced in C11? I'm on C99 right now

Comment: @Koldar `inline` was introduced in C99 and `_Generic` in C11. Which is at this point a 7 years old standard and hardly something new.

Comment: I have to downvote this for suggesting `_Generic` in a question that mentioned neither C11 nor `_Generic`, and for subjectively describing C's only mechanism for _open_ generic programming as "old-fashioned" (I will give you "quite dangerous").  `_Generic` can only be used when you can enumerate all of the concrete types that will be used with it, so it is not a replacement for the technique OP was using.

Comment: @zwol When using the C tag, it is assumed that standard C is used. As per the C tag wiki. Thus advice for how to implement this in standard C is neither subjective nor off-topic, even though the question was indeed tagged standard C. As for enumerating all the types, that's a non-issue: `_Generic((x), a*: a, b*: b, default: def)(x)`. Now rather than resorting to petty revenge-down voting, you might want to go to meta and study why SO discourages primarily-opinion based answers. If you include a coding-style rant at the bottom of every post you make, you are just distracting from the topic.

Comment: How do you use `_Generic` with `qsort()` and `bsearch()`?  Or how should `qsort()` and `bsearch()` be modified to be able to use generics?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's a good question, as those are perfect examples of the "old school" generic programming. I suppose it is possible to wrap those functions in macros and wrapper functions to achieve type safety. The main challenge being to replace the function pointer that bsearch expects with a type safe one.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that may preserve both warnign absence and code readability might be the introduction of the following macro:

```
#define PDOC(...) void*

//function declaration
bool matchByName(const PDOC(struct person*) p);

//function definition
bool matchByName(const PDOC(struct person*) _p) {
  const struct person* p = (const struct person*) _p;
  //insert awesome code here
}
```

In this way you don't generate the warning but you preserve signature readability (although it costs you some addtional types).